# WordPress: Fatal error with no additional information thrown upon plugin activation

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

I'm building a plugin at the moment. In the "index"-page (the one with the information about the plugin) I use `require_once`. When I want to activate the plugin, a fatal error is thrown:
`Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.`
No more information is shown.

I commented all the lines except `require_once plugins_url('php/hooks.php', __FILE__);` out and checked the path. Still triggering a fatal error. The problem has to be the `require_once` command but I don't know what to do about it. I have used this command in the exact same context, file and version of WordPress before and it worked back then.

Comment: try to enable wordpress debug and see errors in the log.

Comment: @yuyokk: I have debugging enabled all the time. Nothing useful there.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. `require_once` needs a path, not an URL.